# About input type="number" open number pad in mobile but how open numpad for input type="password"

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser, numpad

I am try to open the number pad in mobile browser for  `<input type="password" />`
but i am not able to do this

when I set `<input type="number" />`
in my HTML page the mobile browser open the number pad for this field when the viewer click on this field
How i can force the mobile browser to to open number pad for input type of `<input type="password" />`

Comment: normally there are allready numbers on the keypad for input type password

Answer (score 1):

Solution for webkit browsers (displays the text of a number type input as disc)

```css
#numberPassword {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberPassword" />
```

Comment: Thank you    I put in my page , but it show its content rather than password form (***)  and it not works properly

Comment: It does not work and it still show the number without password format

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Does the snippet above work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#numberPassword {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberPassword" />
```